# Having trouble while adding elements to array and print them

Tags: c, arrays, printing

I'm trying to create an array which has size depended upon input elements count. After that I want to print it but I'm getting very strange outputs.

```
int main(void)
{
    int input_arr;
    int i,size=0;
    int arr[size];

    while(input_arr!=-1){
        printf("enter positive int");
        scanf("%d",&input_arr);

        arr[size]=input_arr;
        printf("%d",arr[size]);

        for(i=0;arr[i]!='\0';i++){
            printf("%d ",arr[i]);
        }

        size+=1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

> `33 3 3 3 3 3 6487488 enter positive int3.`

It gives output like this and after a while it stops taking elements. I could not recognize where am I doing wrong.

Comment: you declared an array of size 0. I'm more of a c++ person, but I think your array size is fixed at the time you declare it, when size is 0. (presumably you enter UB when you start writing past the end)

Comment: you are right but it did not solve my issue. now i get output like 4202816 1 37 after i put first element. Maybe pointers may help me but first i want to know why this is not working and how can i fix it.

Comment: What is your desired output? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: This code still shows you declaring an array of size 0 and writing past the end. Undefined behavior. (Please provide exact input, output, and expected output)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C the size of the array is fixed the moment you define it. Increasing the `size` variable does not increase the array size. Therefore you immediately get a buffer overflow the moment you read the first element. You can instead declare a large array like this:

```
static const int maxSize = 4096;
int arr[maxSize];

int main(void)
{
    int i, size=0;

    while(size < maxSize){
        printf("enter positive int");
        scanf("%d", &arr[size]);
        ++size;

        for(i=0; i < size; i++){
            printf("%d ",arr[i]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Alternatively you can use `malloc` and `realloc` to grow the array dynamically.